# Processor Generation Compatibility

Tags: cpu

AMD A6-3620 APU with Randeon(tm) HD Graphics 2.20 GHz. What generation is it? I've tried looking it up through device manager but it didn't show me.

Comment: What do you mean by "generation" exactly?

Comment: According to [official specs](https://www.elgato.com/en/game-capture-hd-support), Elgato Game Capture HD60 requires i5-2xxx with 2 GHz or higher. Your A6-3620 APU is about half as fast as i5-2400. As such I don't think they are compatible. ==== Next time please edit your [original question](http://superuser.com/questions/1101741/processor-generation-compatibility) instead of starting a new post.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you're looking for by trying to find out which 'generation' the APU is but, it's a Lynx/Llano, originally released in 2011.  I *think* it would technically be first generation.